# How can I change my MONGODB_URI for my mlab provisioned DB on Heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku, connection-string, mlab

Say I accidentally let the cat out of the bag and made my `MONGODB_URI` public for a database provisioned by mLab on Heroku -- is there a way to reset/regenerate/change my connection string?

For example, my connection string looked like: 
`mongodb://heroku_g20xzxs8:vc8k708rh1qqgr17luq7satqct@ds045622.mlab.com:41222/heroku_g20xzxs8`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First immediately set new a password via mongo CLI:

login:

```
$ mongo --port 27017 -u siteUserAdmin -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

change password:

```
$ db.changeUserPassword("yourusername", "S0m3NeWPaSW0RdPxmt1oOfL")
```

After, you may delete username enterily with ***db.removeUser(username)*** and re-create it ***db.createUser()***. Up to mongo 2.6  [db.removeUser()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.removeUser/#db.removeUser).

It's possible to update your entire user [db.updateUser()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.updateUser/) .

To deploy the new string do heroku:

```
 $ heroku config:set MONGODB_URI=mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@host1:port1,host2:port2/dbname
```

If you do not want to the CLI/command line way, remove user entirely and create a new one on mLabs - 'Initial Home Screen' / 'MongoDB Deployments' / Users / 'Name-Readonly-X'. Click 'X' to delete and done. Add new user and deploy the new string after that.

Answer (score 1):

The key here is to realize what the connection string is made up of. In my case with a single-node plan, my connection string defaulted to this format

`mongodb://dbuser:dbpass@host:port/dbname`

which contained some generated user and password for the database. If you go into your mLab management portal via your Heroku app's dashboard or open it with the Heroku CLI:

`heroku addons:open mongolab`

You can go into the Users tab and create a new user. With the new username and password, you can [update your heroku config variable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#setting-up-config-vars-for-a-deployed-application).

For example, in this case, the generated username was `heroku_g20xzxs8` and the password was `vc8k708rh1qqgr17luq7satqct`. If you make a new user `new_db_user` and password `th1$PasswordR0x`, your updated connection string, and the value of your MONGODB_URI config variable will look like:

`mongodb://new_db_user:th1$PasswordR0x@ds045622.mlab.com:41222/heroku_g20xzxs8`

Once you've tested that your updated `MONGODB_URI` is in working order, go ahead and delete the auto generated user -- Yay, no more vulnerabilities!